# Dropping Events in a Custom serializer

Tags: java, flume, flume-ng

i have a Custom Serializer on an ElasticSearch sink.
Based on some field values, which i read in the serializer, i might have the need to drop the event.

I haven't found a way how to do that.
Any ideas?

thanks,

Helmut